# Where system stores 16 segment addresses while segment registers are 4?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, x86-16, cpu-registers, memory-segmentation

In real mode memory addressing there are 16 segments made with the size of 64KB, and there are 4 segment registers, so where system store those 16 addresses?

```
 0. 00000
 1. 10000
 2. 20000
 3. 30000
      :
      :
14. E0000
15. F0000
```

For example, if my system respectively uses the first 4 segment starting addresses in CS, DS, ES, and SS.
Where will the remaining 12 addresses be stored?

Comment: Why do the other addresses need to be stored?  In some sense, addresses are constants, and constants don't need to be stored as they can be conjured any time.  (If we were to count up all the possible segments in a 20-bit address space, there are 64k of them: 0x00000, 0x00010, 0x00020, 0x10000, 0x10010, ..., since they can start on any 16 byte boundary and they can overlap.)

Comment: Segmentation isn't intended to let you easily access all 1MiB at once.  You carve it up into possibly-overlapping chunks, or short segments that *start* at some multiple of 16; you might not use the whole 64K.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to store them anywhere. You load your segment address (which doesn't have to be on a 64K boundary, by the way - only at a multiple of 16) into the segment register of your choice/need when you use it.

For example, let's say I want to load some value at physical address 0x12345 into `al`. Then I'd do `mov ds, 0x1234` followed by `mov al, [0x5]` (note that this instruction implicitly uses `ds:`, but you could also specify it manually) - or `mov ds, 0x1000; mov al, [0x2345]`, or any other combination that adds up to the value I want (physical address = segment * 16 + offset). I'd usually organize my memory in such a way that the things I often need together are reachable with the same segment, i.e. are within 64K, so I wouldn't have to switch segments all the time.